# How to have your own Node structure in a forward_list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, forward-list

How do I combine my own typical 
typedef Node { 
   int data; int data1; Node* next} 
to make a forward_list ?  I think I can throw away the Node* next (i.e. typedef Node { int data, int data1} ) and make the STL manage the pointers through forward_list, but then how do I delete a pointer to a particular Node ? The standard iterator on forward_list is a long int and not a Node *; so if I use my Node to create a linkedlist, how do I delete a Node* from that list ?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I can throw away the Node* next and make the STL manage the
>   pointers

Yes this is what you should do

> how do I delete a pointer to a particular Node ?

```
std::forward_list::remove
std::forward_list::erase_after
std::forward_list::remove_if
std::forward_list::pop_front
std::remove
std::remove_if
```

give different algorithms to delete nodes from the list

> how do I delete a Node from that list ?

Follow the example in this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/erase_after/)

Comment: I do not think you answered my question completely, in other words, once my struct Node is in a forward_list, how do I get back a Node* from the forward_list ? For example, someone asks me to write a function : removeNodefromList (forward_list<Node> input_list, Node* to_remove) - how would you write it ? If I use an iterator to iterate over elements, I cannot seem to get back a Node * even though each of the elements are Node *

Comment: you should replace your function with something like `removeNodefromList (forward_list<Node>, std::forward_list<Node>::const_iterator)` and use a standard deletion algorithm. With c++ library you want to use iterators in replacement to pointers. Note that `std::list` is more efficient in this situation

Comment: Sure, if it is changed into an iterator, it is trivial. So lets say, someone gives me a struct Node and asks me to make a single linked list out of it, I should not be using the forward_list STL in that case ? Because the designer is going to ask me to write all the APIs in terms on Node and Node* since he has no concept of an iterator, hence won't be okay with me redefining the API from a Node* to an iterator. So I should write my own linkedlist class and deal with the pointers myself ?

Comment: If someone else designs the structure `Node` and gives you the responsibility to manage a container of `Node` instances then it's your responsibility to specify how the `Node` instances are indexed. If for some reason he imposes `Node*` indexing, you can still use a C++ container and return the address of the instance in case of a query. For deletion, you need to iterate through the container and find the instance with the address he provides, once found you can get an iterator and use a C++ deletion algorithm

Comment: Since `Node*` arithmetic cannot be used to iterate the list, at least use `Node const* const` for immutable instances and `Node* const` for mutable instance